# subset the data frame based on some criteria in R

Tags: r, subset, distance

In the list, there are three data frames. First, I want to select the data frame of the fewer rows to be my reference frame. And then I want to subset the other data frames based on the minimum distance from the values of the reference data frame. 
here is the example:

## Data

```
a<- data.frame(name=c("a1","a2","a3","a4"), x=c(10,15,59,21),y=c(12,16,20,30))
  b<- data.frame(name=c("b1","b2","b3","b4","b5"), x=c(8,9,2,-1,13),y=c(7,1,5,10,0))
  c<- data.frame(name=c("c1","c2","c3","c4","c5","c6","c7"), x=c(1,5,6,2,3,10,-8),y=c(2,-3,7,4,6,15,8))
  all<- list(a=a,b=b,c=c)
```

Here a is chosen as a reference as its nrow=4.
now I want to compute the distance as follows

```
a1b1, a1b2, a1b3, a1b4,a1b5     
a2b1, a2b2, a2b3, a2b4,a2b5
a3b1, a3b2, a3b3, a3b4,a3b5
a4b1, a4b2, a4b3, a4b4,a4b5
```

which distance is minimum of each row the corresponding will be added to the subset of the data frame b called sub_b as follows:

## Expected Result

```
> sub_b
  name x y
1   b1 8 7
2   b3 2 5
3   b1 8 7
4   b3 2 5
```

similarly, compute the distance between a and c then subset c based on the minimum distance

# a1c1, a1c2, a1c3, a1c4,a1c5, a1c6, a1c7
   # a2c1, a2c2, a2c3, a2c4,a2c5, a2c6, a2c7
   # a3c1, a3c2, a3c3, a3c4,a3c5, a3c6, a3c7
   # a4c1, a4c2, a4c3, a4c4,a4c5, a4c6, a4c7

and the sub_c data frame should be as

# Expected Result

```
> sub_c
  name x y
1   c3 6 7
2   c5 3 6
3   c3 6 7
4   c5 3 6
```

finally, the new list is  new.all<- list (a=a, sub_b=sub_b, sub_c=sub_c)

## Here is My Code

```
lessRow<- lapply(all, function(x) nrow(x)) 
  lessRow<- which.min(lessRow)   # set the reference frame 

     A<- matrix(a$x, a$y, ,nrow=4,ncol = 2) # convert data frame to matrices 
     B<- matrix(b$x, b$y, ncol = 2,nrow = 5)
     C<- matrix(c$x, c$y, ncol = 2,nrow = 7)

     library(geosphere)     # compute the distances
     dis.ab<- distm(A, B,distGeo)
     dis.ac<- distm(A, C,distGeo)

# select which points of dataframe b is closest to points a
       minm.ab <- apply(A, 1, function(x) {
        dm <- distm(x, B , fun=distGeo)
        return(which.min(dm))
      }) 
# select which points of dataframe c is closest to points a
       minm.ac<- apply(A, 1, function(x) {
         dm <- distm(x, C , fun=distGeo)
         return(which.min(dm))
       }) 
# subset based on the minmuim distance 
       sub_b<- b[minm.ab,]
       sub_c<- c[minm.ac, ]
# create a new list of new data frames by keeping the reference frame (a) as it is.
       new.all<- list (a=a, sub_b=sub_b, sub_c=sub_c)
```

The question is how to do so in the loop as the number of data frames is more than 3.

Comment: Why do you change order of rows in `C` and `c` and same for `B` and `b` ? If you want to convert dataframe to matrix you can do `as.matrix(b[-1])`.

Comment: There is no change except that in the data frame there is the characters column which I need it. whereas matrix don't accept character. And in the distm function I must give matrices as arguments

Comment: Compare `b` and `B`? Shouldn't they be the same then? They have different values in your code. You are changing the rows orders in them.

Comment: yes, you are correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can separate the reference dataframe and remaining dataframe based on number of rows. Then calculate the distance between each row in reference dataframe with the remaining one and get the minimum distance, use that to subset the rows in dataframe and get a list of dataframes.

```
library(geosphere)

inds <- which.min(sapply(all, nrow))

ref <- all[[inds]]
remaining <- all[-inds]

output <- lapply(remaining, function(x) {
            x[apply(ref[-1], 1, function(y) {
                   which.min(distm(y, as.matrix(x[-1]), fun = distGeo))
               }),]
              })
```

Combined dataframe :

```
c(list(ref), output)
```

Comment: your code doesn't give the same result as what I expect

Comment: @ Ronak shah One more thing, how can I keep the sequence of the data frames after processing? In this example, the data frame (a) is the less what if the data frame (b) was, the less then the order of the new list will be (b, a,c).I want it to be the same as it is (a,b,c). how can I arrange them and maintain the sequence

Comment: @Jisika In that case, instead of assigning to `output` assign to `all[-inds]`. So do `all[-inds] <- lapply(remaining, function(x) {...rest of the code as it is` So that you have answer in `all` and in same order.

Comment: @ Ronak Shah. Thank you very much